# Get a list of Power BI Dashboards - 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, powerbi

I have been trying to run a simple test. Console application that connects to a Native AAD token and reads a list of Dashboards on the Power BI Tenant. its now been a day and I am stuck on 403 as soon as the request to the Power BI API is sent. I have a console app and Postman... same results.

- Power BI Pro Trial
- AAD Token created via https://dev.powerbi.com/apps
- I can get the auth token from AAD and permissions granted on AAD

Please help. here is the console app.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tokenString = GetToken();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", tokenString));
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var x = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }



    #region Get an authentication access token
    private static string GetToken()
    {          
        string clientID = "f6e83929-565c-4200-b75e-5a61b38c5633";           
        string redirectUri = "https://dev.powerbi.com/Apps/SignInRedirect";
        string resourceUri = "f6e83929-565c-4200-b75e-5a61b38c5633";
        string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<My Tenant ID>/oauth2/authorize";

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
        string token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine(token);
        return token;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this, I found the answer after 3 days of reading.

Check out the answer on this post https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Can-t-use-any-Power-BI-APIs-get-403-even-with-token/m-p/639593#M18738

seems that "**https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api**" excactly, not the application resource, not updated api url's exactly the url above. Changed it and everything worked

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the linked blog post into your answer and make it more clear. It might be that the linked content will someday yield a 404 error.